# Generate Random URL, but URL length can't be changed fro some reason?

Tags: javascript, html, random

As of recently I've been working on a site as a bit of a hobby during class. On this site there is some basic text a single button and a text field. when you press the button it generates a random URL and then you can add your own extension to it. At the moment it's to send people to random .onion domains. My current problem is that I cant get the length of the URL to be set to a random length. Here is my code, if you can recommend a fix that would be great. `

```html
<body>
  <script>
    var 'x' = Math.random() * 20
  </script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function randomString() {
      var chars = "0123456789abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
      var string_length = 'x';
      var randomstring = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
      }
      document.randform.randomfield.value = randomstring;
    }
  </script>
  <form name="randform">
    <input type="button" value="Generate A New Base URL" onClick="randomString();">&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="randomfield" value="">
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: `var 'x' = Math.random()*20` <-- that is not valid And `var string_length = 'x';` <-- I did not know that X was a length.

Comment: these kinds of errors, and their causes, should be easy to see using your browser's developer console.  Have you tried having it open when running your code and seeing what it reports?

Comment: @epascarello I was trying to use x as a random variable, but I dont know how. That's what I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

This works after fixed: `'x'` => `x`

```js
        var x = Math.random() * 20;
        function randomString() {
          var chars = "0123456789abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
          var string_length = x;
          var randomstring = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
            var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
            randomstring += chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
          }
          document.randform.randomfield.value = randomstring;
        }
```

```html
      <form name="randform">
        <input type="button" value="Generate A New Base URL" onClick="randomString();">&nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="randomfield" value="">
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
        var x = Math.random() * 20;
        function randomString() {
          var chars = "0123456789abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
          var string_length = x;
          var randomstring = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
            var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
            randomstring += chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
          }
          document.randform.randomfield.value = randomstring;
        }
```

```html
      <form name="randform">
        <input type="button" value="Generate A New Base URL" onClick="randomString();">&nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="randomfield" value="">
      </form>
```